# Scale the distance between ticks on x-axis in gglot r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a graph like this. I am interested in the minor change between the range (-3.5, 0.5), however, the occupied only a small portion of the x-axis, so that it's hard to interpret.

I tried to use transform to log scale for better visualization, however, it apparently not works for negative values.

So is there any method to expand this region to make the graph look nicer?

## Code:

```
ggplot() + geom_line(data = Final_diction, aes(x = Final_diction[,1], y 
= Final_diction[,4])) +
xlim(-3.5,20) +
geom_vline(xintercept=c(-0.5,0.5), linetype="dashed", color = "red") +
geom_vline(xintercept=c(-0.25,0.25), linetype="dashed", color = "blue") +
theme_bw() +
theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 20)) +
theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 18))
```

[image]

Comment: you want only (-3.5, 0.5) to be plotted.?

Comment: @geekzeus I want the distance between (-3.5, 0.5) ticks could be larger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
library(ggforce)
library(ggolot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=disp, group=1)) +
  geom_line() + facet_zoom(xlim = c(15, 20))
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try adding the `xlim = c(minor value, major value)` option of ggplot, and use the range which works better for you

Something like that:

```
ggplot() + geom_line(data = Final_diction, aes(x = Final_diction[,1], y 
= Final_diction[,4])) +
xlim(-3.5,20) +
geom_vline(xintercept=c(-0.5,0.5), linetype="dashed", color = "red") +
geom_vline(xintercept=c(-0.25,0.25), linetype="dashed", color = "blue") +
theme_bw() +
theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 20)) +
theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 18)) +
xlim = c(-4, 1)
```

Comment: T hank you for your suggestion! This approach do better depicts the details within the range (-4,1), however, other information within (1,20) was discarded, which is not what I want.